# Create error Message with runtime value

Tags: warning-messages, mathlink-or-wstp

I've written a Mathematica package (see [here](https://github.com/QTechTheory/QuESTlink/tree/improving_validation)) which uses WSTP to call a C/C++ library. Some possible user-errors are known by the package and can be detected and reported by the front-end package code. However, some user-errors are reported by the C library and must be sent on to Mathematica; these error messages are not known a-priori, and the errors cannot be detected by my package itself.

This seems incompatible with the standard way to report package errors, using `Message`. For example, if the package function `myFunc` accepts positive integers, the canonical way to handle this is:

```
myFunc::badarg = "First argument must be a positive integer"

myFunc[x_Integer] :=
    If[ x<0, 
        (Message[myFunc::badarg]; $Failed),
        ...
    ]

(* of course there are more elegant ways to handle this usign patterns *)
```

The result looks like this in Mathematica:

[image: notebook snippet]

In this example, we see the message in `myFunc::badarg` is fixed, and set a-priori.

In theory, even my WSTP functions can be given messages of this kind;

```
:Begin:
:Function:       my_C_func
:Pattern:        myFunc[x_Integer]
:Arguments:      { x }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Integer }
:ReturnType:     Manual
:End:
:Evaluate: 
    myFunc::badarg = "First argument must be a positive integer"
```

Still, these error messages are fixed.
But now consider when `my_C_func` involves an error detected by the internal C library:

```
void my_C_func(int x) {

    try { 
        library_func(x);
        WSPut...

    } catch(string err) {

        // must send 'err' back to Mathematica
        WSPut...
    }
}
```

I would like to 'channel' `err` to the front-end, to report it like I would the `myFunc::badarg` error message. Unfortunately, `Message[]` accepts `symbol::tag` which is a-priori set, and we don't know what message `err` contains.

Is that at all possible? Otherwise, how can I *fake* the look of `Message`?

Currently, my hacky solution is to completely forego using `Message`, instead using `Echo`.

```
// must send 'err' back to Mathematica
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);

WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Echo", 2);
WSPutString(stdlink, err);
WSPutString(stdlink, "Error ");

WSEndPacket(stdlink);
WSNextPacket(stdlink);
WSNewPacket(stdlink);

WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
```

which produces
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll mention one somewhat hacky way; inserting a string into `Message`.

In my WSTP templates, I'll use a variable in `myFunc::errormsg`:

```
:Begin:
:Function:       my_C_func
:Pattern:        myFunc[x_Integer]
:Arguments:      { x }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Integer }
:ReturnType:     Manual
:End:
:Evaluate: 
    myFunc::errormsg = "`1`"
```

Then, in my C++ code, I'll invoke `Message[myFunc::errormsg, err]`:

```
void my_C_func(int x) {

    try { 
        library_func(x);
        WSPut...

    } catch(string err) {

        // must send 'err' back to Mathematica

        WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);

        // Message[myFunc::errormsg, err]
        WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Message", 2);

            // myFunc::errormsg = MessageName[myFunc, "errormsg"]
            WSPutFunction(stdlink, "MessageName", 2);
            WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "myFunc");
            WSPutString(stdlink, "errormsg");

            WSPutString(stdlink, err.c_str());

        WSEndPacket(stdlink);
        WSNextPacket(stdlink);
        WSNewPacket(stdlink);

        WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
    }
}
```

Though yet untested, this *should* give me the desired behaviour. Though surely there is a better way!

Comment: Oh joy, it works!

Comment: This is not a hacky way. `Message` is *designed* to be called with multiple arguments. Normally you don't have a fixed message string. You would have a message template with several slots, which are filled from the rest of `Message`'s arguments.